# unable to build or run simplex chat android app on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to run this android app - https://github.com/simplex-chat/simplex-chat
on android studio, I tried both window 11 and linux mint android studio, still failing to run.

To run android app on android studio , i first went on linux mint and tried running the script- sudo sh scripts/android/build-android.sh stable
and then waited for 6 hours and then after 6 hours i got the error

The error message displayed:

complete error - https://justpaste.it/ar4cy

and here in short

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Settings file '/tmp/tmp.qJL7kOI0wj/simplex-chat/apps/android/settings.gradle' line: 8

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.

Could not find method dependencyResolutionManagement() for arguments [settings_39saka3mixatfk5k339106kkm$_run_closure1@38df7799] on settings 'android' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings.
```

please help me how to resolve the error and successfully build the project. I am struggling from last 10 days , I want to run simplex chat app on android studio, i have tried on window 11 , i failed miserably, so I dual boot my laptop and install linux mint and install android studio on linux mint , still i am failing, I tried everything, run all code on terminal also still failed when trying to run app on android studio getting this error

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process /home/tanmay/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.18.1/bin/ninja with arguments {-C /home/tanmay/androidstudio23april23imp/03)androidstudioprojects/01)simplexchatapp/apps/android/app/.cxx/Debug/4eo5s253/arm64-v8a app-lib}
ninja: Entering directory `/home/tanmay/androidstudio23april23imp/03)androidstudioprojects/01)simplexchatapp/apps/android/app/.cxx/Debug/4eo5s253/arm64-v8a'

ninja: error: '/home/tanmay/androidstudio23april23imp/03)androidstudioprojects/01)simplexchatapp/apps/android/app/src/main/cpp/libs/arm64-v8a/libsimplex.so', needed by '/home/tanmay/androidstudio23april23imp/03)androidstudioprojects/01)simplexchatapp/apps/android/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/4eo5s253/obj/arm64-v8a/libapp-lib.so', missing and no known rule to make it

Task :app:buildCMakeDebug[arm64-v8a] FAILED
C/C++: ninja: error: '/home/tanmay/androidstudio23april23imp/03)androidstudioprojects/01)simplexchatapp/apps/android/app/src/main/cpp/libs/arm64-v8a/libsimplex.so', needed by '/home/tanmay/androidstudio23april23imp/03)androidstudioprojects/01)simplexchatapp/apps/android/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/4eo5s253/obj/arm64-v8a/libapp-lib.so', missing and no known rule to make it

Task :app:buildCMakeDebug[armeabi-v7a] FAILED
C/C++: ninja: error: '/home/tanmay/androidstudio23april23imp/03)androidstudioprojects/01)simplexchatapp/apps/android/app/src/main/cpp/libs/armeabi-v7a/libsimplex.so', needed by '/home/tanmay/androidstudio23april23imp/03)androidstudioprojects/01)simplexchatappt/apps/android/app/build/intermediates/cxx/Debug/4eo5s253/obj/armeabi-v7a/libapp-lib.so', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Please help me.

Comment: What's the error? It tells you on line 8 in the the first error. What is on line 8?